# Tweepy not giving me all the media files in a tweet

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to get all the media files (images, videos) from tweets in a one year time-frame. It is giving me the media files but the problem is that if a tweet has more than 1 image (lets say 4), then I will only get 1 image not the other 3.

Code:

```
import tweepy
import sys
import pandas as pd
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token =''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
media_files = set()
data = []
columns = ["image", "time", "likes", "retweets"]
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,screen_name='infokpgovt').items(2000):
    if 'media' in status.entities:
        for image in status.entities['media']:
            print(image['media_url'])
            print (status.created_at)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If there is more than one media in the tweet, you have to look at the `extended_entities` field:

```py
for image in status.extended_entities['media']:
```

You can read more about that in the Twitter API documentation [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/extended-entities).

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I read the docs and started using extended_entities as well, the problem with this approach is that if there is a thread with 6 pictures (4 in the first, 2 in the second) it will only give me the last 2 ones, it will exclude the first 4. I can't understand this behavior.